# Why does this function fail at runtime?

Tags: runtime

I have the following piece of code, why does it fail at runtime?

Code from MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainuilayout_fragment);

    mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    home_directory = mPrefs.getString("home_directory", home_directory);
    JNIdc.config(home_directory);
```

This is the error that I get

```
2020-02-27 13:08:35.997 19527-19527/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.android.emulator, PID: 19527
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data``/app/com.android.emulator-DSqX_PGjDkqsKqoajwOoYw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.android.emulator-DSqX_PGjDkqsKqoajwOoYw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libdc.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1011)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1657)
        at com.android.emulator.JNIdc.<clinit>(JNIdc.java:6)
        at com.android.emulator.JNIdc.config(Native Method)
        at com.android.emulator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:67)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7028)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7019)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2933)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1627)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6722)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Can you please add your code?

Comment: code from MainActivity.java? or which file you want me to get from?

Comment: Yes, and please highlight line 67.

Comment: ```JNIdc.config(home_directory);```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show the whole MainActivity?

Comment: Yes, I changed my question. I want to add whole code from MainActivity. The message from stackoverflow said too long by 20184 characters. Should I put the code from oncreate() part?

Comment: Yes, do that...but normally you could post enough characters...

Comment: Don't write it in a comment. Edit your question and add it there. This way, you can post the whole MainActivity.

Comment: I added it into my question. Sorry, this is my first post on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that libdc.so is missing. It needs to be added first before it recognizes JNIdc.config. I receive an error when I try to solve the line for android.mk before running ndk-build. It says

```
/home/user/Desktop/project/app/shell/android/jni/Android.mk:21: /home/user/Desktop/project/app/shell/android/jni/../../core/core.mk: No such file or directory
```

make: *** No rule to make target '/home/user/Desktop/project/app/shell/android/jni/../../core/core.mk'.  Stop.